# Grails 2.5.0 - Command Object handle POST request with JSON

Tags: grails, command-objects

I have a form set up to send a POST request to a Grails controller, which is using a Command Object as its one parameter. The Command Object contains some properties binding correctly along with a List of items, which is not binding correctly. What I'm doing is sending the other parameters normally via the POST request but wrapping the list up as a JSON string, as I'm not sure of another way to send a list via POST (aside from, say, an XML string). What's the final step in getting the command object to bind the list properly from the string, or is there a better way to send the list to the command object?

Edit:
Here is a simplified version:

Testing the URI:

```
request.forwardURI = 'list1=[{"listprop1":"a","listprop2":"b"}]&prop1=c&prop2=d'
```

The command objects:

```
class MyListCommand {
    String listprop1
    String listprop2

    static constraints = {
        listprop1 nullable: true
        listprop2 nullable: true
    }
}

class MyCommand {
    List<MyListCommand> list1 = [].withLazyDefault {
        new MyListCommand('[]')
    }
    String prop1
    String prop2

    static constraints = {
        prop1 nullable: true
        prop2 nullable: true
    }
}
```

The form:

```
<form action="${createLink(action: 'myAction')}" method="post">
                <div ng-repeat="list1 in list1array">
                    <input type="hidden" name="list1[{{ $index }}].listprop1" value="{{list1.listprop1}}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="list1[{{ $index }}].listprop2" value="{{list1.listprop2}}"/>
                </div>
                <input name="prop1" type="text">
                <input name="prop2" type="text">
            </form>
```

Comment: You need to include the command object as well as your form (or how you are composing the data you are posting) in order for anyone to give you a good answer on how to approach this.

Comment: I added the relevant info. I put in the forwardURI instead (which I simplified from Fiddler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending the request like this:

```
request.forwardURI = 'list1[0].listprop1=a&list1[0].listprop2=b&prop1=c&prop2=d'
```

## Even better

A better approach is to use Ajax with the [g:remoteForm](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#remoteFormSubmission) tag.

Comment: The form is encoding it as list1%5B0%5D.listprop1=a&list1%5B0%5D.listprop2=b&prop1=c&prop2=d when I see it in Fiddler. Is that a problem? I'm getting an error "Property [list1] of class [class com.mypackage.MyCommand] cannot be null"

Comment: I added the code. Note that AngularJS is populating list1array. I'm sorry the names are getting funky in this simplified code.

Comment: Ah, you're not using `<g:form>`. Since you want to use ajax, try a remote form instead: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#remoteFormSubmission

Comment: I actually don't want to use ajax. I just want to submit the form via post normally. When I tried <g:form>, I got the exact same results on Fiddler.

Comment: I ended up using AJAX as you suggested and got it working that way, if you want to put that as a separate answer.